# Set time out still runs when i clear the div

Tags: javascript

I have a setTimeOut which i have assigned to a div like this:

```
function update(div,data){
    div._myTimer = setTimeout(function() { update(data);},1);   
}
```

But for some reason when i remove the div from the page the time out still runs.

For example lets say i clear the parent of `div` by doing:

```
parent.innerHTML = '';
```

Shouldn't this cancel my time out because the div no longer appears in the DOM? Or have i misunderstood something.

Comment: You have misunderstood something, but reading the documentation should have cleared it up.

Comment: Well my logic was if i removed `div` then the function tied to it would also go with it which would be similiar to just using return false or clear time out.

Comment: The function "tied to" it? That's not any terminology I 'm aware of. If you did `var arr = [0, 1]; div._myVariable = arr;` would you expect `arr` to change in any way after the div is removed?

Comment: Well i meant as a property of div thus if the div goes so did the execution of any thing linked with it but never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout once set does not need the div to exist. You should remember the reference for the timeout and clear it manually before you clear the div.

When you remove the div by setting the innerHTML of the parent, you can look for every div that is going to be removed and check if it has the _myTimer property set and in the case you clear the timer.

```
for (var i=0, ilen=parent.childNodes.length; i<ilen; i++) {
    if (parent.childNodes[i]._myTimer) {
        clearTimeout(parent.childNodes[i]._myTimer);
    }
}
```

Or if you delete the div this way, you can acces the reference directly:

`clearTimeout(div._myTimer);`
`div.parentNode.removeChild(div);`

Not with innerHTML = '', this way you have more control over the elements that will be removed

Comment: How would you generate unique references to it to remove at a later point ?

Comment: You already have one reference to it in you div. Before you remove the div, remove first the reference. Or create your own manager class for it with an array or object, where you store the references. Perhaps together with the id of the div element.

Answer (score 1):

What's returned from the `setTimout` method isn't something that is needed from the timer to run, it's just a handle that can be used to stop the timer.

Losing that handle only means that you can't use the `clearTimeout` method to stop the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood. Removing the div from the document doesn't clear the timeout. You'll have to use `clearTimeout` to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `clearTimeout` to do it. You can try something like this:-

```
function update(div,data){
   div._myTimer = setTimeout(function() { update(data);},1);   
 }
function remove_div(event) { 
    // do stuff
    clearTimeout(timerId);
}
```